# Matrix to list of matrix group by column names in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a matrix with 6000 columns and each column belongs to one of 100 "groups" i need. I need to convert this matrix into a list 100 smaller matrices. This is a toy example of what i have:

```
  mat = cbind(c(2,2,2),c(3,3,3),c(4,4,4),c(1,1,1))
  colnames(mat) = c("2018.3 1","2018.3 2","2019.1 1","2019.2 2")
```

so the "group" is identified by the last name of each colname, here there are 2 groups. The result I need would look like:

```
list(cbind(c(2,2,2),c(4,4,4)),cbind(c(3,3,3),c(1,1,1)))
```

I've been thinking and I think it should be something like this:

```
lapply(do.call(cbind,sapply(something here to find the columns in each group)))
```

but i haven't figure out how exactly to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Obtain the last part of each column names
groups = sapply(strsplit(x = colnames(mat), split = " "), function(x) x[2])

#Go through each unique column name and extract the corresponding columns
lapply(unique(groups), function(x) mat[,which(groups == x)])
#[[1]]
#     2018.3 1 2019.1 1
#[1,]        2        4
#[2,]        2        4
#[3,]        2        4

#[[2]]
#     2018.3 2 2019.2 2
#[1,]        3        1
#[2,]        3        1
#[3,]        3        1
```

OR

```
lapply(split(1:NCOL(mat), sapply(strsplit(x = colnames(mat), split = " "),
                                 function(x) x[2])), function(i) mat[,i])
#$`1`
#     2018.3 1 2019.1 1
#[1,]        2        4
#[2,]        2        4
#[3,]        2        4

#$`2`
#     2018.3 2 2019.2 2
#[1,]        3        1
#[2,]        3        1
#[3,]        3        1
```

Comment: You could also do `groups <- sapply(strsplit(x = colnames(mat), split = " "), `[`, 2)` or `groups <- gsub(".*(\\d+)$","\\1", colnames(mat))`